# Is it feasable to create a program that can select an image out of a number of images given. e.g. a spiral galaxy versus an ellpictcal one

Tags: vb.net

I want to create an algorithim that can distinguish between two (or more) images, and find the one I want it to. For example, a program that takes two images, a spiral and elliptical galaxy image and selects the spiral one by noticing differences in the two. I'd like to do this is VB.NET.

I'm not a beginner, can this be done in a reasonable amount of time? What kind of libraries will I need and is there anything else?

Comment: This isn't supposed to be answer, just an idea to point you in one direction: To me that sounds like a typical use case for machine learning. I guess your best bet would be to build a neural network that can learn from example images...

Comment: Building a neural network is way out of my skillset, all I want is some kind of practical application for detecting differences in two images.

Comment: Well, if you just want to compare them pixelwise, it is simple. But as soon as you want to compare them by some semantic aspects/context, you will need some kind of classifier. You can build them yourself, which is probably quite hard to do, or let the machine do it by itself :-) Just a thought, though!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes close to what you are asking as below, more complex comparison would require some kind of machine learning network.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  PictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample 
  Pictures\Tulips.jpg")
  PictureBox2.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample 
  Pictures\Tulips.jpg")
Dim a As Boolean = AreSameImage(PictureBox1.Image, PictureBox2.Image)
If a Then
  MsgBox("Identical image")
Else
  MsgBox("Different images")
End If
End Sub

Public Function AreSameImage(ByVal I1 As Image, ByVal I2 As Image) As Boolean
Dim BM1 As Bitmap = I1
Dim BM2 As Bitmap = I2
For X = 0 To BM1.Width - 1
  For y = 0 To BM2.Height - 1
    If BM1.GetPixel(X, y) <> BM2.GetPixel(X, y) Then
      Return False
    End If
  Next
Next
Return True
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, image processing (signal processing in general) is one of the most difficult things to program. What our brain does so easily, distinguishing and classifying sounds and images, is awfully difficult for a computer.

If you want to implement an algorithm that does something as "simple" as telling apart galaxy shapes, besides programming skills you'll need to know some stuff about image processing and algorithms, or either be very familiar with a specific image processing library. For this second option, there are a lot of image processing libraries for .NET, you have multiple choices, you can just Google them, but still you'll have to learn the basics of image processing, and then learn to work with that library.

So, responding to your question: "can this be done in a reasonable amount of time?". If you haven't done any image processing programming before, I would say no.